# Как деобфусцировать/расшифровать код python pyarmor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, обфускация

Я обфусцировал код через pyarmor, но сохранил только старую версию программы, из-за чего потерял очень много кода, как можно деобфусцировать код? (Пробовал mystics, но он ничего не делает, через pyarmor unpacker (при запуске программы такая же ошибка) появляется `ImportError: libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` запускал через termux ubuntu)

Comment: Даже если получится, то все переменные и общая структура будет выглядеть как каша. Быстрее заного написать чем в этом месеве разбираться и реконструировать.

Comment: @amgarak переменные легче заменить, чем переписывать, у меня был баг, который я долго фиксил, не знаю теперь, смогу ли снова, а из импортов у меня только os и time, поэтому вряд ли с ними будет большая проблема